# Integrating jupyter notebook (ipython) into org-mode notebook

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way I can link in jupyter notebooks (ipython) into the org-mode notebook? The same way other files (images) can be brought in? If it is possible will the outputs are also seen in the note (and inputs are runnable?), or only code itself? A dummy's guide would be a lot more appreciated as I'm new to emacs and configuring things are not straightforward. Many Thanks

Comment: [`ob-ipython`](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython) does exactly that.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ipython` in an `org babel` code block.

1) start in a shell `jupyter-console`

2) copy the json filename from `/run/user/1000/jupyter` to `:session` argument in the source code header.

an example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session kernel-9735.json :exports both :results raw drawer

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn-whitegrid')
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x));


#+END_SRC
```

for plot image output `M-x org-display-inlineimages`

### prerequisites:

you will need to add ipython to your org-babel:
    (require 'ob-ipython)

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
   (ipython . t)))
```

and generally:

```
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t
    org-src-preserve-indentation t
    org-src-tab-acts-natively t)
```

I found that ipython is no longer using `readline` so it causes some strange formatting, this is solved using:

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "/PATH/TO/FOO/BAR/BAZ/ipython3 --no-banner --classic --no-confirm-exit")
```

for inline images:

```
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images 'append)
```

I recommend to check out [scimax](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax) which is an Emacs starterkit for scientists and engineers.
and [ein](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook) which works a treat!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping there is a way you can do like `include test.ipynb` which links in the whole notebook rather than I copy paste snippets of code, do you think  there is any way?

Comment: you can `:tangle` and thus create a py file from all your blocks, and you can import within the python code using `import`